# Using MSMQ without installing MSMQ on client machines

Tags: c#, wcf, queue, msmq

I use WCF to execute some code on a server (takes a long time). The request to execute that code is send from several client machines within the local network (TCP).

Since the code takes a while to execute and there are a bunch of clients, I need to somehow queue the requests.

I thought about using MSMQ as queueing mechanism. As far as I understood, MSMQ has to be installed on the client machines as well, not just the server.

Is it possible to not have to install MSMQ on all clients? Are there any alternatives to MSMQ, or simpler ways to have a queue in between the clients and the WCF-service?

Comment: There are lots of alternative queue systems, yes. You can research them fairly easily

Comment: I stumbled accross ZeroMQ, it's a lightweight, simple library. Probably gonna use it. It doesn't come with a persisting queue out of the box, which might turn off some people.

Was wondering if I was right about the need to install MSMQ on client machines? No way around that?

Comment: Not that I know of. There are a few others as well as Zero, e.g. rabbitMQ and others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to not have to install MSMQ on all clients?

No. You must have msmq installed on all machines which want to participate in the sending and receiving of messages.

> Are there any alternatives to MSMQ

Yes, many.

> or simpler ways to have a queue in between the clients and the
> WCF-service?

WCF uses msmq for queued transport on-premise. However, it is possible to use WCF with Azure Service Bus if you want to run in Azure. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-relay/service-bus-relay-tutorial)